# Literally Canvas Official Example "Exporting Images" not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Literally Canvas official example of exporting images is not working.

http://literallycanvas.com/examples/export.html

After I copied exact the same code from the webpage and put it on my own webpage, it still did not work.

On the official page, a new about:blank page will appear.

On my webpage, it refreshes the webpage.

Source code of my webpage (I don't know whether can I post the URL of my webpage):

```
<html>

<head>
<!-- stylesheet -->
<link href="/static/css/literallycanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- dependency: React.js -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>

<!-- Literally Canvas -->
<script src="/static/js/literallycanvas.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Canvas -->
<!-- where the widget goes. you can do CSS to it. -->
<!-- note: as of 0.4.13, you cannot use 'literally' as the class name.
     sorry about that. -->
<div class="my-drawing"></div>
<p></p>
<!-- kick it off -->
<script>
    LC.init(
        document.getElementsByClassName('my-drawing')[0],
        {imageURLPrefix: '/static/img'}
    );
</script>

<!-- Export Image -->
<form class="controls export">
    <input type="submit" data-action="export-as-png" value="Export as PNG">
</form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var lc = LC.init(document.getElementsByClassName('literally export')[0]);
        $('.controls.export [data-action=export-as-png]').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.open(lc.getImage().toDataURL());
        });
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I got an error message in console: $ not defined.

And I added this before the script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another error message showed up :

```
literallycanvas.js:3626 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
at Object.init (literallycanvas.js:3626)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (canvas.html:38)
at j (jquery.js:3137)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3249)
at Function.ready (jquery.js:3455)
at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3496)
```

URL of my webpage: http://chaldea.biz/canvas.html

Comment: works fine for me - what browser are you using? ... let me guess ... google chrum - broken again is it

Comment: Google Chrome. I have disabled popup blocker/ad blocker in content setting, I think.

Comment: seems it only works in firefox (and other mozilla based browsers) ... IE and Edge also don't work - must be some over zealous security feature in those browsers

Comment: OK. I will try it on Firefox. Thank you!

Comment: it will work in firefox

Comment: instead of `window.open(lc.getImage().toDataURL());` can you `console.log(lc.getImage().toDataURL());` - if that outputs something that looks valid, then the issue is purely with window.open

Comment: I opened the console and I found an error message there "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at canvas.html:36", which is "$(document).ready(function() {" this line. I guess the whole thing inside the ready(function() did not load up

Comment: did you include jquery library in your page?

Comment: Yea, see updated question description

Comment: if you included jquery then you couldn't have `$` undefined - that's jquery